# Comando no Shell

Tags: script, shell, ssh

Estou precisando copiar o último arquivo criado em um diretório para outro via `ssh`.

Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no user@IP "cd /home/user/backup_database/hour/; cp "`ls -1trap | grep -v '/$' | tail -n 1`" ~/"
```

O comando retorna o seguinte erro quando executo o script:

> cp: cannot stat 'shutdown.sh': No such file or directory

Se puderem me ajude com comando ou alguma outra solução.

Comment: Essa regex bate com o nome de arquivo que você quer copiar?

Comment: Não está funcionando pois quando você usa os acentos graves, ele realiza a listagem no direito onde o código foi executado e não no lado do servidor.

Comment: Fabricio. Sim.. executando o comando direto no servidor ele realiza a cópia

Comment: @andré crie um `script.sh` com o código responsável por duplicar o arquivo e execute o código `ssh user@host 'bash -s' < script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Os comandos utilizados estão corretos, porém o uso das aspas no lugar errado que ocasiona o erro.

**Segue:**

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no user@IP "cd /home/user/backup_database/hour/ && cp `ls -1trap | grep -v '/$' | tail -n 1` ~/"
```